# Encountering an error with a TextField when implementing a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyAppc extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        
        body: SafeArea(child: CustomScrollView(slivers:
        
        
        
        [
          
         SliverToBoxAdapter(child: 
          
          
          MyCustomTextField())]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class MyCustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
       minLines: null,
      expands: true,
      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        
      ),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0), // Adjust text style as needed
    );
  }
}
```

**Before adding CustomScrollView, the TextField functions correctly. However, after adding CustomScrollView, an error occurs with the TextField.And i dont want to give any height or width to the textfield(wrapping a container with fixed height)**

Comment: an error occurs?

Comment: yes..didnt you get any error?

Comment: Why don't you wanna give a height value to TextField?

Comment: The SliverToBoxAdapter is expecting a static height of the child. You need to wrap your MyCustomTextField with SizedBox with height: 50 (or any desired height) of TextField